# PHP Return HTML List From an Array of Url's

Tags: php

I am working on a test project and was hoping to get some help in the form of a little code review...not looking for an easy answer!  My instructions are:

"Complete the function getBreadcrumbNavigation() so that it returns a string of HTML code. Assume the
variable $breadcrumbs contains an array of Webpage objects with valid values for its member variables.
The returned HTML code should be an ordered list of links. The last entry in the array is the current page
and should show the anchor text, but should not have an anchor tag around it."

Here is what I have, would this accomplish the goal?  Thanks for the help guys, I am still learning.

```
<?php
class Template {
private $breadcrumbs;

public function getBreadcrumbNavigation() {

    foreach ($breadcrumbs as $anchorText) {
        if ($urlName != $myUrl) {
            echo("<li><a href=\"$urlName\">$anchorText</a></li>\n");
        } else {
            echo("<li>$url</li>\n");
        }
    }
}
}

class Webpage {
public $anchorText, $myUrl;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this homework of some sort?

Comment: Kind of, it's a skills assessment

Answer (score 0):

So I will try to help guide you...but not give you the answer.

The questions asked to RETURN the value...so echo is not *technically* correct here.

The variables you are using inside your function are meaningless, where are they coming from? What is setting them?

You are on the right track with your foreach line but remember what the task says *breadcrumbs is an array of objects* so the values you need are attached to the `$anchorText` variable which would be 1 element (an OBJECT) inside your ARRAY of `$breadcrumbs`

Additionally a valid unordered list has this structure

```
 <ul><li>STUFF</li><li>MORE STUFF</li></ul>
```

*The last entry in the array is the current page and should show the anchor text, but should not have an anchor tag around it*

Your solution does not solve this. You will be able to find out the # of elements in the array with a specific function AND modify your `foreach` statement to get the index and value to figure out what element you are currently iterating through.

I'm also not sure if you want `$breadcrumbs` as a class variable...maybe a function param for `getBreadcrumbNavigation`

Comment: Thank you so much Ray, I am not looking for an answer here just guidance.  I appreciate your help as I don't have a mentor to bounce code off of at this point.

Comment: I left out the beginning of the instruction that said:
"Refer to the following PHP class"
     <?php
     class Template {
     private $breadcrumbs;
     public function getBreadcrumbNavigation() {

     }
     }

     class Webpage {
     public $anchorText, $myUrl;
     }
     ?>

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format a comment in code form :/

Comment: ok thats fine, then disregard this part "I'm also not sure if you want $breadcrumbs as a class variable...maybe a function param for getBreadcrumbNavigation"

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the value of $breadcumbs as parameter to constructor while instantiating the object and assign to private variable for accessing from the class.

> Assuming your breadcrumbs name and url name is same  eg:  Contact 
>   /contact/
>        Laptop   /laptop/

```
    <?php
class Template {
private $breadcrumbs;
public function __contruct($bd){
       $this->breadcrumbs = $bd;
}

public function getBreadcrumbNavigation() {

    foreach ($this->breadcrumbs as $anchorText) {

            echo "<li><a href='/" . $anchorText .'>" . $anchorText . "</a></li>";

    }
}
}
$breadcrumbs= 'Get your Breadcrumbs as an array' ;
$obj = new Template($breadcrumbs);
$obj->getBreadcrumbNavigation();
?>
```